# Laravel Session Flash

Tags: php, laravel, session

I am using laravel session to pass messages to the view.

This is a sample code

In my Controller

```
$request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');
return redirect()->back();
```

In my view

```
@if(Session::has('status'))
<p class="alert alert-success">{{Session::get('status') }}</p>
@endif
```

My question is, this session flash does not work correctly. which means I did not get any paragraph as mentioned in controller. but if I used session()->put(), it was works..

Comment: try clearing cache

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect()->back()->with('status', 'SOME ERORR');
```

Blade

```
@if (session('status'))
<p>{{Session::get('status')}}</p>
@endif
```

Comment: So the error is not related to your code.check your session driver and config.php
@Anonymous

Answer (score 0):

You can use the session directly like:

```
session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');
```

instead of using:

```
$request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');
```

and in the blade file use it like this :

```
@if(Session::has('status'))
    <p> {{ session('status') }} </p>
@endif
```

Hope it worked. :)